# Extracting the group that has a specific groupby aggregate value in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm doing a pandas groupby for a specific DataFrame which looks like this

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |

And when I apply `df.groupby('Group')['Value'].mean()` I get

Group
A     1.5
B     2.5
Name: Value, dtype: float64

My end result is trying to find the group that has the max groupby aggregation (ie: Group B) as my result

I understand that groups.keys() is an option to list the keys but would there be a way to repeatedly get the groupname for a specific aggregation. ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

By default, `groupby` sets your grouping column as index of the aggregation. Use `idxmax`:

```
df.groupby('Group')['Value'].mean().idxmax()
```

Output: `'B'`